# Strange function type

Tags: haskell, types, pointfree, monomorphism-restriction

I've a beginner's question about types in Haskell: Having a function like:

```
f i xs = (sort xs) !! i
```

How do I define the function `f0 xs = f 0 xs` without explicit use of xs?
Just taking

```
f0 = f 0
```

does not work...

ghci shows me the folling types:
`f :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> a`
`f0 :: [()] -> ()`
But ":t f 0" gives `f 0 :: Ord a => [a] -> a`.

Why is that? Why do I get this type for f0? Why is there any difference between the type of "f0" and the type of "f 0"?

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I think it has something to do with this: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your particular definitions: if you do it (as you should!) with the standard implementation, the same thing happens.

> Prelude> let f0 = maximum
>   Prelude> :t f0
>   f0 :: [()] -> ()

Anyway, first you should give `f` a signature.

```
f :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> a
```

If you do that for `f0` as well, all will work fine:

```
f0 :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

Now the question is, why would ghci deduce such a stupid signature? It's the [Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)'s fault. That means, whenever you define something "as a constant<sub>(-applicative form)</sub>", i.e. a simple equation

```
c = any odd stuff
```

then the compiler refuses to give that automatically a polymorphic signature (like, with `a` type variables in it). Instead, it defaults to the "simplest usable" type, which for an `Ord` constraint unfortunately is the completely useless `()`.

You can turn the monomorphism restriction off, then it'll work even without a signature:

> Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction 
>   Prelude> let f0 = maximum 
>   Prelude> :t f0 
>   f0 :: Ord a => [a] -> a

But honestly, on the top level you should *always use manual signatures* anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much :)! Well, before I used OCaml a bit - so I got used to write function without type annotations...